# Generate a table from the last lines of a list of xts objects

Tags: r, xts

I have a list of xts objects. I'd like to get a data.frame with the last lines of each levels of the list.

My list looks like:

```
a <- xts(matrix(1:4,2),as.Date("2012-01-01")+0:1)
b <-list(a,a*5)
> b
[[1]]
           [,1] [,2]
2012-01-01    1    3
2012-01-02    2    4

[[2]]
           [,1] [,2]
2012-01-01    5   15
2012-01-02   10   20
```

I would like to get:

```
[,1] [,2]
2    4
10   20
```

The column names are the same in each levels of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Henrik's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10583645/271616), you could also use a combination of `lapply`, `do.call`, and `last`:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(b,last))
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks. Not that it matters, but I get this warning though: `Warning message:
In rbind(deparse.level, ...) :
  mismatched types: converting objects to numeric`

Comment: @PLapointe: that's because you constructed `a` with an integer matrix (`1:4` is an integer vector), but `a*5` creates a numeric matrix. `b <- list(a*1,a*5)` will make the Warning disappear.

Comment: @PLapointe Following on from Joshua's explanation, if you really wanted everything to be integer: `storage.mode(b[[2]])='integer'`  (Using `as.integer(a*5)` was my first guess, but that goes horribly wrong :-)

Answer (score 1):

As `b` is a list you can use any of the `*apply` family members such as:

```
vapply(b, "[", i = 2, rep(0,2))
```

If the objects in `b` have different numbers of rows the following should work:

```
vapply(b, function(x) x[nrow(x),], rep(0,ncol(b[[1]])))
```

Note that in the first version you have to adapt the `2` in `rep(0,2)` if your objects have more columns, or you use the constructions from the second example.

Note that you have to use `t` on the results to obtain the format as you want it:

```
t(vapply(b, "[", i = 2, rep(0,2)))
```